# How does one create a unit vector from character to target without it scaling based on distance?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to calculate the direction to shoot a bullet which goes from my character to the mouse cursor.

```
 unitvecx = (mousex-playerX)/np.sqrt((mousex**2 +playerX**2))
 unitvecy = (mousey-playerY)/np.sqrt((mousey**2 +playerY**2))
```

and when I scale the constantly updated change in bullet position with this in order to calculate direction in my game loop with

```
if bullet_state is 'fire':
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletX += bulletX_speed*unitvecx
        bulletY += bulletY_speed*unitvecy
```

I notice that as I move the cursor closer to my character position, the bullet speed slows down. I print the unit vector out constantly and see that it does indeed change. To me this makes no sense, because the unit vector should always have magnitude 1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're calculating the unit vector wrong. For a target `T` and a source `S`, the direction vector is `D = T - S`. The unit vector is `U = D / norm(D)`

So in 2 coordinates,

```
Dx = Tx - Sx;
Dy = Ty - Sy;

Ux = Dx / sqrt(Dx**2 + Dy**2) = Dx / sqrt((Tx - Sx)**2 + (Ty - Sy)**2)
Uy = Dy / sqrt(Dx**2 + Dy**2) = Dy / sqrt((Tx - Sx)**2 + (Ty - Sy)**2)
```

Your current code does

```
Ux = Dx / sqrt(Tx**2 + Sx**2)
Uy = Dy / sqrt(Ty**2 + Sy**2)
```

Since you're already using numpy, why not use its features?

```python
player_loc = np.array([playerX, playerY])
mouse_loc = np.array([mouseX, mouseY])
uvec = mouse_loc - player_loc
uvec = uvec / np.norm(uvec)

if bullet_state is 'fire':
    fire_bullet(bullet_loc[0], bullet_loc[1])
    bullet_loc = bullet_loc + bullet_speed * uvec
```